# Caching a slow changing resource

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, glassfish, java-ee-7

I am retrieving a remote resource that takes about 400 ms to retrieve and transform into a Java object.  This object has the potential to be referenced over high volume of requests to my JAX-RS web service (the objects owner).  Is there some built in caching mechanism that allows me to store an object by id/hash and retrieve it at a later point in time (like a hashmap but with some way to expire the resource after 3600 seconds).

I've looked at:
https://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/caching_static_resources_in_glassfish

and it looks promising but the linked ExpiresFilter no longer exists that I can find and that only resolves the issue of a remote system calling the JAX-RS method while many other methods rely on this method (and therefore the method is called directly within java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any standard caching mechanism in Java EE or Glassfish, but I think [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has exactly what you're looking for, i.e. robust cache implementation: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

It's thread-safe and can be configured to expire items whenever you want. I have been successfully using it in Java EE apps and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

JCache (JSR 107) is a standard caching API for Java applications, and was supposed to make it into Java EE 7, but ended up being deferred to Java EE 8. But you can use it as 3rd party library in Java EE applications.

Here's a (slightly out of date) article explaining how to use it.
http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-jcache-jsr-107

And the spec and RI are here.
https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec